# How can I count the occurrence of a key based on array value

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
[furnitures] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [fi_id] => 8
        [price] => 15.00
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [fi_id] => 8
        [price] => 15.00
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [fi_id] => 7
        [price] => 15.00
    )
    [3] => Array
    (
        [fi_id] => 7
        [price] => 15.00
    )
    [4] => Array
    (
        [fi_id] => 8
        [price] => 15.00
    )
    [5] => Array
    (
        [fi_id] => 9
        [price] => 15.00
    )
)
```

I want unique fi_id from it and I also want to count the occurence from it. How many times is this being repreated. Does PHP has any built in function for it?

Like unique items are 7,8,9 and 7 is repreated 2 times, 8 is repreated 3 times and 9 is repreated 1 time.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried using "array_count_values" but it iis for 2d simple arrays. not if values are in array as well.

Comment: Hi, i am unable to answer this question, here i am pasting that might works

Comment: $fid=[];
foreach ($array['furnitures'] as $key => $value) {
 $fid[$value['fi_id']]=$value;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
//Here you get unique Ids
$uniqueFiIdList = array_unique(array_map(function ($el) 
{ 
   return $el['fi_id']; 
}, $furnitures));

//Here you get the total unique occurences
$totalUniqueFiId = count($furnitures) - count($uniqueFiIdList);
```